# Requires string as left operand, not reversed Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is my code so far:

```
def mirror(s, v, m):
    rev = reversed(v)
    if(v in s):
         if(rev in s):
              if(m in s):
                  return True
    return False
str1 = "abcmcba"
str2 = "abc"
str3 = "m"
mirror(str1, str2, str3)
```

it is supposed to return as true but keeps giving me the error: 
requires string as left operand, not reversed

Comment: `reversed()` returns an iterator, not a string. You then are effectively doing `if <iterator> in <string>`, which is an error.

Comment: Even with the fixes regarding `reversed`, the method does not consistently do what I think it's intended to do (detect whether a string `s` equals a string `v` mirrored around a character `m`). For example, try `str1 = 'NOTAMIRRORabcmcba'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can streamline that function to the following:

```
def mirror(s, v, m):
    return m in s and v in s and v[::-1] in s
```

Note that I've put the fastest checks first so that it doesn't waste time on slower operations unless they're necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, reversed does not return a string it returns an <strike>generator</strike> iterator.

Try this:

```
rev = ''.join(reversed(v))
```

Comment: It returns an iterator, not a generator [function|expression].

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it, i changed:

```
 rev = reversed(v)
```

to

```
rev = v[::-1]
```